# How to find the x, y coordinate (or index) of values in a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a 2D array I created using this,

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(4)
arr_2d = arr.reshape(2,2)
```

The array looks like this

```
print(arr_2d)
[[0, 1],
 [2, 3]]
```

I am trying to get the location of each entry in `arr_2d` as an x, y coordinate, and eventually get an array that looks like this,

```
print(full_array)
[[0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 1],
[2, 1, 0],
[3, 1, 1]]
```

Where the first column contains the values in `arr_2d`, the second column contains each value's x (or row) coordinate and the third column contains each value's y (or column) coordinate. I tried flattening `arr_2d` and enumerating to get the index of each entry, but I was unable to get it in this form. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: you could do ye-olde nested for-loop way

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.unravel_index()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html):

```
x = arr_2d.flatten()
r = np.vstack((x,np.unravel_index(np.arange(arr_2d.size),arr_2d.shape))).T

# r = array([[0, 0, 0],
#           [1, 0, 1],
#           [2, 1, 0],
#           [3, 1, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

Both `flatten()` and `np.unravel_index()` use by default a row-major order, so we knows that the right order is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the nicest way, but it works (assuming this is what you are after):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(4)
arr_2d = arr.reshape(2,2)  

arr_2d[1][0] = 5 # to illustrate a point

print(arr_2d)
dimensions = arr_2d.shape
for y in range(dimensions[0]):
    for x in range(dimensions[1]):
        print(arr_2d[x][y], " (x:", x, " y:", y, ")")
```

renders:

```
[[0 1]
 [5 3]]
0  (x: 0  y: 0 )
1  (x: 1  y: 0 )
5  (x: 0  y: 1 )
3  (x: 1  y: 1 )
```

which you can just put in another array